# Usage of the slang "having a go" in AmE

Tags: prepositions, american-english, slang

Imagine a man is going to get married and his close friend sees that the girl his friend has chosen is not a good one [By accident, he (the friend) knows the girl's background in detail] and wants to warn his friend about that girl (but very openly and in a debate). Please have a look at my self-made sentence and let me know if the bold preposition is a correct one or I have to modify it:

> - One hundred people have had their go **at** her before you.

**Note:** the number "100" here is a type of exaggeration to show an emphasis of the severity in my language and have no idea if it works in AmE.

Comment: I think I know what *have a go* means from my exposure to British English (I've never heard it in American English before), but you seem to have a different meaning in mind . . .  I'm not sure how to answer.

Comment: Where did you find the sexual slang meaning of "have a go at someone"? Are you sure it's AmEng? To "have a go at **something**" means to attempt to do something. To "have a go at **someone**" means to express strong, usually in anger, criticism.

Comment: To have a go at someone or something means what Mari-Lou has said and does not have a sexual connotation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA please have a look at this [link](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/have-a-go)
But I was not sure about the preposition at. Whereas the only preposition in common use referring to an individual was "at" on google, I decided to use it to make sure if it works here or not. Meanwhile, I've heard the compound verb "have a go" from an AmE southern close friend last year when he was expressing his mother's viewpoint about his girlfriend.

Comment: Online slang dictionary is not a very reputable source, it also defines **have a go** (note the absence of a preposition) as [*to make an attempt.*](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/have-a-go). I think J. Reynold's sources are better but all the dictionary entries use the pronoun ***it***, as in : "have a go at it", and not one provides any examples of usage. If he can come up with a few citations these would be helpful.

Comment: `he was expressing his mother's viewpoint about his girlfriend. ` What exactly did he say? Is that the *self-made* sentence? Did the mother say *exactly* that about your friend's GF? The sentence is not idiomatic, first of all it should be **A hundred men / guys**  not "one hundred" and not "people" unless she's also a lesbian. Note how EVERY answer uses the indefinite article, and not one uses the term *people*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am completely sure he as a native American speaker used this verb to indicate the message his mother was trying to convey, but I do not remember the exact sentence. This is why I mentioned my sentence as a self-made one. Perhaps, in spite of the fact that this is a rare slang, it is a regional difference. (Please consider that two native speakers have already confirmed the usage just on this thread. Jim and Andrew.)

Comment: Please consider that snailplane, Lambie, Peter, Andrew and myself have expresses their *doubts* about its usage.

Comment: @A-friend More likely, your friend picked it up from contact with British English.

Comment: So, I'm going to drop it out and discover an AmE alternative for that. Would you possibly let me know now if there is a suitable word which fits my example? To be more clear I'll provide some example expressions that each one would work as the expression in my question.

Comment: @snailplane In our mother language instead of what I mentioned above and as Jim completed it: **"I’m sorry to have to tell you that a hundred guys have had a go at her before you"** we say: **_these are direct translations_** --> **"A hundred guys have had rubbed their hands at her"** OR **"A hundred guys have had used her like a _(facial)_ tissue and then threw her away."**

Comment: Why don't you like the easiest, and the most idiomatic expressions? **He/she has slept with XYZ wo/men** OR **He/she's been with a hundred wo/men** Your direct translations are comprehensible, albeit distasteful, but they are not natural. If you were a writer then I'd say go ahead, be creative, be original, don't use cliches, but don't turn around and ask if your invented sentences sound natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only source I found which actually provides an example of usage comes from Urban Dictionary under the entry of "[go](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=go)".  leverichm suggests that ***with*** or ***at*** are the most appropriate prepositions to use.

> [image: UD definition of "go"]

If the OP wants to this expression, then I suggest that he rephrase it as:

> **A** hundred **guys** have had **a** go **at/with** her before you.

Answer (score 3):

I presume the OP wants a sentence that is direct and explicit, judging by their self-made sentence. I suggest that the following are more idiomatic in British English and American English.

- Sorry mate, but she's a **whore** / [ho](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ho) / [slut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slut) / [skank](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skank).
- I hate to break this to you, but she will [**screw**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/screw) anyone/anything **with a** [**pulse**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pulse).

For something less crude try:

- Sorry buddy, but she's **been** / **slept with** a hundred guys.
- Sorry pal, but she's [**damaged goods**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/damaged%20goods), if you know what I mean.

I *suppose* in an appropriate context, *to have a go at someone* could imply casual sex, but  the expression **[have a go at](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go_2)** *something* in British and American English means to attempt to *do* an activity.

- I **had a go at** [Zumba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zumba) but it nearly killed me.
- She tried **having a go** at writing a novel herself.

While **have a go at** *someone*,  especially in British English, means to either physically or verbally attack someone.

> British
>   Attack or criticize (someone):
>   1. *[‘The problem is my aunt and uncle are always having a go at me.’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have_a_go_at)*
>   2.  *My teacher had a go at me earlier, just for missing one sodding homework. I was fuming.*
>   3. *The two boys were going at each other like mad dogs*  ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_a_go))
>   4. *I heard you had a go at Jack the other night*

Comment: Just for clarification purposes, "been with" and "damaged goods" are more delicate ways to express this, while your first and last are a bit more crude and direct.

Comment: @J.R. point taken, and rectified.

Comment: I think some people would find the phrase *damaged goods* deeply offensive, FWIW.

Comment: @snailplane because telling a friend that their girlfriend  has slept with a 100 men is somehow more acceptable? The entire premise of the OP is offensive to women.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But I think *damaged goods* fails to be any "less crude", as you put it… I think it's more offensive than the other terms in your answer, to be honest.

Comment: @snailplane  The expression is used euphemistically, by itself *damaged goods* (the technical term) is completely inoffensive compared to *whore*, *ho*, *slut*,  etc.

Comment: The term inherently carries a sexist double-standard. We would unlikely describe sexual experience as damaging/ruining/spoiling a man. I don't see it as especially crude, but I wouldn't use it myself because it is incompatible with my values. I wouldn't describe someone as a *whore* or *slut* for similar reasons, though I personally like employing vulgar terms in some contexts.

Comment: Only moralizers call women that first row of words. Also, if a man sleeps with 100 women, would one say the man is damaged goods? I really don't know people who go around qualifying the number of men a woman has slept with nowadays. Most people no longer care about this in the West, people. At least the ones I hang around with. I don't hang out with fundamentalists or sexists or backward cultural types...so...

Comment: @Mari-LouA At my age it's impossible to keep up with current slang, so it's entirely possible that you can "have a go" at a woman to imply that you had sex with her.  Otherwise, I agree the entire conversation is offensive, but nevertheless [people do talk this way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wM248Wo54U).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your use of *at* is correct. But it is standard to use *have a go* instead of *their go.* We would also more conventionally use *a hundred,* especially if we mean *about a hundred* or simply *a lot.*

Assuming you mean males, perhaps more naturally:

> A hundred guys have had a go at her before you.
>
> I'm sorry to have to tell you that a hundred ....
>
> As a friend, I feel I have to tell you that a hundred . . . .

References for "have sex/intercourse with":

[*The Free Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+go+at+it): **have a go at it**; have sexual intercourse with
[*Vocabulary.com Dictionary*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/have%20a%20go%20at%20it): **have a go at it** (idem)
[*WordWeb Online*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/HAVEAGOATIT): **have a go at it**: (idem)

Comment: Could you please provide a reference with this meaning.

Comment: @Mar Updated. I am surprised to find relatively few "widely recognized" authorities giving the definition on a quick search. This meaning is familiar to me. I'll try to find examples from a corpus search later.

Comment: The links, good ones too, are all for ***have a go at it***, but I suppose that does not exclude other personal pronouns... but I'm not 100% certain. The pronoun **it** is often used to mean *sex*, "I did it with Bob"

Answer (score 2):

It really depends how crude you want to be. There are a hundred ways to make this statement :)

> She has slept with every guy in [the city/neighborhood]. 
>   She has f**ked every guy... 
>   She's the neighborhood bicycle; every guy has ridden her. ([1](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=neighborhood+bicycle)) 
>   That girl is a hood rat. ([2](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hood%20Rat))

Answer (score 1):

> Having a go

Is BrE and has many different meanings all relating to "trying to do *something*"

> We are placing bets on the Liverpool game. You want to have a go mate?

If you were to say

> A hundred guys have had a go at her before you.
>   *she has slept with a hundred guys*

You could be saying that a hundred guys *tried to marry* her before your friend did, but it would probably be understood that you are basically calling her a slut since "having a go at *someone*" means you are trying to bed them.

and your friend might say back to you

> Are you having a go *(at me)*?!
>   *are you trying to upset me/rile me up?*

Comment: As you say, the phrase connotes an attempt, and not necessarily a successful one. So, interestingly enough, even though a hundred guys may have "had a go at her," perhaps only two or three were successful. For that reason, I'm not sure this would be the best phrase to use in the O.P.'s situation.

Comment: It's entirely possible that "have a go at her" could mean "slept with her".  As with most slang you'd have to establish meaning from context.

Answer (score 1):

There is a N. American equivalent:

> A hundred guys have had a turn with her.
>
> Everyone's ridden that bike.

Both have the sexual meaning as well as preserving the original concept of "trying out" while still being euphemism rather than an explicit statement.

I agree with [Mari-lou A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/1694/mari-lou-a) that "go at *someone*" usually means to attack, but it also has a meaning of intense sex (eg. *the two were going at it hot and heavy*) in a different sense than in the original post.